# How to make slide image animation when change image in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to make animation when change image A to image B like this...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the image you are loading? from network url, Bitmap image or image drawable from your resources? please be specific what exactly you want to do

Comment: do you want continuous image change like in sliders? or you want change image only once?

Comment: I want to load image from drawable and... I want to change image only once. Thank you for attention me. ><

Comment: I think this is not possible with single image view. This can be done using two imageviews or with ViewSwitcher. hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @QadirHussain I'll try to use ViewSwitcher

Comment: It's very work!!! Thank you again @QadirHussain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we have `ViewPager` to do image slider.